# Can NFC tag take the User to second screen of App in React Native?

Tags: react-native, nfc

Is that possible to write in the NFC tag to take the User to second screen of APP instead of first??My use case informs the user to switch on NFC from settings on the first page and when user switch on NFC settings and scan the tag ,it should go to the next screen instead of main screen.
How to achieve this both in IOS and Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in react native with deep linking, in NFC tag you should write "link", that is navigation, to the screen you want to go, this is similar to push notifications -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! Could you please share any code link on github or something to make it more clear?

Comment: Explore react native deep linking, there should be some sources.

Comment: I was able to achieve using Deep-Linking! Thanks